# How to use open emm to send transaction emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, mail-server, bulk-email

I want to use open emm to send transaction emails to users.

Presently i am using open emm to send newsletter .

I want to send emails to users with content specific to user . ex. transactions. Through asp.net website

In News letter the content is same for every one . But in my case now the content will change from user to user .

And i have to send minimum 5000 emails per day .

And if i am able to send how many emails will i be able to send per min.

Or can i use the stmp server of the open emm in any way to send emails through it.

Comment: You are asking us to do tons of research, while you have done very little. Try something first, if you run into a specific problem - you cannot solve - ask a question. As for the e-mails, 5000 is not much, just make it paste in a text that is different for every user.

Comment: I could not find the results that is the reason i have posted over here . if some can give me a link or some thing info how to do it . i will be happy. And its 5000 for now it may increase to more than a lakh in a year i cannot handle at that time so i want to do scalable solution now it self .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research i gave up idea of using openemm as email server , iam using hmailserver for sending emails . it is solving most of the purpose i have to find out how i am going to do tracking and bounce management in hmailserver like open emm

Answer (score 1):

Santosh,

That is what MAILING LISTS and TARGET GROUPS in OpenEMM is for.  You need to divide your users into different groups and create unique template for each group.

As far as the limit of emails, it depends on the email server you are using. That is you can configure when installing your email server. You can also manage the limit through OpenEMM. I have sent 1000 email per minute with no problems with sendmail but I wouldn't recommend a higher number.

Yes, OpenEMM has a mail server that you can use. In many cases I personally used Postfix and Sendmail with no issues.

If you still have general queries, I recommend you visit OpenEMM's forum:
http://forum.openemm.org/

-Yamen-